# Can I assume the transformation of the domain is the codomain if it is stated that T: V -> W?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

If I have a linear transformation $T: V\to W$, can I assume that the $T(V)$ is "$W$"?

Comment: no${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Wait sorry! I asked the wrong question. let me rewrite. It's been a long day

Comment: $T : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \;\mid\; T(x) = 0 \;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\;$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, so I'm trying to show that a linear transformation of a subset of V is a subset of the linear transformation of V.

Comment: @dxiv I was trying to say that for all v is an element of subset(V), T(v) is an element of W = S(U).

Comment: @dxiv If I can't make that assumption do you know how I'd continue

Comment: @Goldname You have that $\,T(V) \subseteq W\,$ by the definition of $\,T\,$. If you mean "*subspace of W*" rather than "*subset*" then just verify that $\,T(V)\,$ satisfies the definition of a subspace.

Comment: @dxiv No I mean, Let $A \subseteq B$ and I want to show that $S(A) \subseteq S(B)$

Comment: @Goldname What are $\,A, B, S\,$ there? If $\,A, B \subseteq V\,$ and $\,S=T\,$ then that follows from the definition of a function, regardless of whether $\,T\,$ is a linear transformation or not. Sorry, you'll have to make it more clear what exactly is that you are asking, and better do it in the body of the question itself, rather than comments.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, yes that's what A, B, S are. But I need to prove this because I was told that I cannot assume that to be true.. Also, how exactly does this follow from the definition of a function?

Comment: @Goldname $w \in S(A) \implies \exists v \in A \mid w = S(v) \implies v \in B \;\land\; w=S(v) \implies w \in S(B)$

Comment: @dxiv Ah I finally understand your proof. Thanks. This would still work if B = V I assume?

Comment: @Goldname Yes, indeed.