# Why does proving a set is a subset of another only require you to take a single element of the subset?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I don't really understand why to show $A\subseteq B$, all we need to show is that $\exists x \in A$ and $x \in B$?

Doesn't this notation mean that there is a specific element of A inside B, not arbitrary element of A is within B? Hence, you should say $\forall x \in A$, $x \in B$?

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ is not the same as $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That's good to know, but how is that related?

Comment: No. It just means something exists. We know what it is, just not exactly what it is.

Comment: $A \subseteq B$ is equivalent to $\forall x \; ( x \in A \implies x \in B )\,$. In case this is related to your other recent question, my comment there does not translate to what you are asking here.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Oh, so $\exists$ means arbitrary existence?

Comment: @dxiv Just as in your answer, I've known that $\exists$ is generally used to prove that $A \subseteq B$, but why aren't we using $\forall$ instead?

Comment: @Goldname [My comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627505/can-i-assume-the-transformation-of-the-domain-is-the-codomain-if-it-is-stated-th#comment5426067_2627505) started with $\,w \in S(A)\,$. There is an implied universal quantifier, so you should read it as $\,\forall w \in S(A) \implies \ldots \implies w \in S(B)\,$. The latter is indeed equivalent to $\,S(A) \subseteq S(B)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv oh i see, but generally I've seen $\exists$ used instead of $\forall$. Are we supposed to use the latter rather than the former for proving subsets?

Comment: @Goldname `generally I've seen ∃ used instead of ∀` That doesn't make much sense at face value. You should really quote a complete example of such usage, otherwise no one can guess.

Comment: I would imagine that any proofs you've seen in fact begin with "Let $x\in A$.  Then... then... and it follows that $x\in B$, therefore $A\subseteq B$"  In such a proof, we assume nothing about $x$ apart from that it is *some* element in $x$.  It follows then that the same argument works for *every* element in $x$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you've seen that $\exists x \in A (x \in B)$ is equivalent to $A \subseteq B$, but that's false. For $A$ to be a subset of $B$ means that for every element $x$ of $A$, the element $x$ is also an element of $B$, i.e. $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

In practice, we show that $A \subseteq B$ by taking a *generic* element of $A$ and showing it's also an element of $B$. This is possible because the sets $A$ and $B$ are usually given by certain defining formulas. For example, $A$ might be the set $\{m \in \mathbb{N} | \exists n \in \mathbb{N}(m=2n \wedge n \geq 10) \}$, i.e. the set of even numbers greater than or equal to $20$. If we want to show $A \subseteq \{20, 21, 22, ...\}$ we simply take an arbitrary $x \in A$ and show it satisfies the defining condition of $\{20,21,22,...\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.

By your way if $A\subseteq B$ then $B\subseteq A$, because $\exists x\in A;x\in B\implies \exists x\in B;x\in A$. Further more, let's take a simple counter example, $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,3\}$ the statement $\exists x\in A;x\in B$ is true,  exists a member of the set $A$ that is also in the set $B$, but $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

The definition of subset is $\forall x(x\in A\implies x\in B)$ so for every arbitrary $x$ you will take if it is in $A$ it will be also in $B$ so the way to prove subset is $\forall x\in A;x\in B$.

---

Sometimes people say $x\in A\implies x\in B$, this way also works because here $x$ is arbitrary, so it is equivalent to the definition

Answer (score 0):

The single element is an *arbitrary* element of the set you are proving is a subset...

You do not prove $\exists x\in A : x\in B$...

Rather, you prove that $\forall x\in A$, it is true that $x\in B$...